# Run JS script embedded in HTML using Python?

Tags: javascript, python

I have an HTML page like this:

```html
<h1 id="title">Hello</h1>
<script>
  var result = null;
  function bigger(x, y) {
    result = 'font '+x+' got bigger by '+y;
    console.log(result)
  }

  document.getElementById('title').onclick = function(){
    bigger('max', 10)
  }
</script>
```

and I have python variable like this:

```
import js2py

string = "Hello World"
size = 120
tt = js2py.run_file('c://file.htm')
result = tt.bigger(string, 120)
```

and I want to load the html page, then run the function from inside of it.

What I expect as result is `font Hello World got bigger by 120` saved in result variable

I used `import js2py` thinking it will work but it does not as I expected

I just wanna load the html file then run the script from local path `c://file.htm` then run `bigger()` script and get the `result` of its change value from inside my `python.py` script

Comment: js2py only executes JavaScript, not HTML

Comment: @LeoDog896 is there package to run html and js too?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Is this HTML file going to be running in a browser?

Comment: @LeoDog896 i downloaded the html file from the browser instead of downloading it every time i need the script in it and the script changes every hour so i wanna download it once every hour like cache and load the script locally

Comment: Edit your question accordingly then -- try to go for what you are trying to do.

Comment: Use Selenium WebDriver to emulate a browser from Python.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's not pretty, you could extract the JavaScript code from the HTML using BeautifulSoup, then translate it to Python using JS2Py. By executing the Python code, you will get access to the functions directly.

This is not pretty however- since the `document` object does not exist, it will throw an exception upon trying to run the translated JavaScript code. Regardless, here is how it should look like:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from js2py.internals.simplex import JsException
import js2py

html_code = """
<h1 id="title">Hello</h1>
<script>
  var result = null;
  function bigger(x, y) {
    result = 'font '+x+' got bigger by '+y;
    console.log(result)
  }

  document.getElementById('title').onclick = function(){
    bigger('max', 10)
  }
</script>
"""

html = BeautifulSoup(html_code, "html.parser")

js_code = html.find("script").text

try:
    exec(js2py.translate_js(js_code))
except JsException:
    pass

string = "Hello World"
size = 120
PyJsHoisted_bigger_(string, size)
```

I will add that if you say you want the string to be saved to the variable, then you will need to `return` it instead of writing it to the screen with `console.log`:

```js
function bigger(x, y) {
    result = 'font '+x+' got bigger by '+y;

    return result;
}
```